# Exporting data to csv from mysql using SELECT INTO OUTFILE exports all columns in a single column

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to export Mysql view data to csv. I have a large set of data in my database tables more than 15 million. I joined each and every table to a view and I just wanted to export it using the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM database_name
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/filename_1.csv'     
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'    
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

My problem is the generated csv file is not ordered. It is exporting all the columns in the view into a single column in csv file. How can I query it to get the data separately in different columns. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of SELECT *, you need to add all column names there are, espeically when you want a certain order, which you should have done already in the view

Comment: `It is exporting all the columns in the view into a single column in csv file` - I don't think this is case as you have specified a field delimiter. Perhap when you open the file to view it, you specify an incorrect field delimiter.

Comment: *My problem is the generated csv file is not ordered.* Of course, because there is no ORDER BY in your SELECT. *It is exporting all the columns in the view into a single column in csv file.* Of course, CSV is always "one row per a line, all columns of the row in this line".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.